# alfred is not swichting to finder if finder is on a separate space macos

Tags: macos, alfred

Macos: 13.4 (m1)
alfred: 5.1.1

If i create 2 'virtual' desktops.

- desktop 1
  contains only one active app 'Finder'.
- desktop 2
  contains only one active app 'Safari'.

Staring point `desktop 1`
if i call alfred `command + space` (for me)
[image]
alfred appears and if i search for `safari` and hit enter, my focus is moved to `desktop 2` where `Safari` resides. (expected behaviour)

if i do this from `desktop 2` and i type `Finder` nothing happens.

but if i'm on the same desktop where Finder resides it does move `Finder` on top of all the other applications and becomes in focus.

can anyone explain what is going on?
This is only `Finder` all other Applications work fine.

thx

if i call alfred and type `finder` I expect that i'm moved to the finder winndow even if that is on a different virtual desktop